# Poor performance of large number of viz::Widget3D in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, visualization, vtk

Using several thousands of viz::Widget3D in OpenCV is very slow. I tried v3.4.3 and v4.0.0 on Windows with Visual Studio 2017. This code snippet takes over 5s to execute the timed part (`t0` to `t1`) and viewing is very choppy afterwards:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  constexpr double n = 100;

  viz::Viz3d window("Viz3d");

  window.setFullScreen();
  window.showWidget("Coordinate Widget", viz::WCoordinateSystem());
  window.spinOnce();

  auto t0 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 

  for (double x = 0; x < n; x += 1)
    for (double y = 0; y < n; y += 1) 
      window.showWidget(to_string(x+y*n), viz::WArrow({x, y, 0}, {x+1, y+1, 0}, 0.02, viz::Color::bluberry()));

  auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 

  window.spin();

  fmt::print("\nTime: {}ms", chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t1-t0).count());
  fmt::print("\nVersion {}.{}.{}{}\n", CV_VERSION_MAJOR, CV_VERSION_MINOR, CV_VERSION_REVISION, CV_VERSION_STATUS);
  return 0;
}
```

It seems that widget management imposes a huge overhead. Is there any other way to display thousands of widgets (text, lines, arrow) with low latency? I tried `viz::WWidgetMerger` and it's even slower.

**EDIT**

BTW, I need only "immediate" mode rendering. I'm not modifying the widgets after they are shown.

Comment: Thousands of widgets, I would consider as performance problem in general. `viz::Widget3D` sounds somehow like OpenGL. What if each widget manages it's own GL context - 1000 of context switches for one update of all. IMHO, this would be definitely a performance problem. How comes that you need such a big number?

Comment: @Scheff I need to annotate each pixel (voxel) of 2D and 3D images with text and vectors. This is routinely done in VTK, which is wrapped by OpenCV to provide `viz::Widget3D`

Comment: May be, I took `Widget` too literally. I'm not sure that it's a widget (of a widget set like e.g. a [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) in Qt). Out of curiosity, I had a look into source [`cv::viz::Widget::Impl`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/viz/src/widget.cpp) and found references to `vtk`. Class libraries, built on top of class libraries, built on top of class libraries. Everything has already been done somewhere - just combine it to get something new. The draw-back: if you get performance issues (or it doesn't work properly), where to start the search?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment wasn't really a help (not at all). Could there be anything else to do such annotations? May be a tutorial of OpenCV or VTK to "cheat" from?

Comment: @Scheff There are 2D options, but I was looking specifically for 3D one and I don't see any other way of doing it, except of defining my own meshes for everything, which is too low level.

Comment: Concerning your last idea: I used Qt's `QPainter` to annotate 3D (OpenGL) rendering. Qt may internally render 2D using OpenGL as well but I never looked at source code to see how (not yet). (The performance hit was unrecognizable but I didn't try with 1000s of...) This was actually not that complicated. - I converted 3D coordinates to 2D using exact the same matrices which I passed to the GLSL shaders. Depth sorting could become an option if necessary as the z coordinates come out as well (and are just discarded currently). Text rendering isn't quite cheap in general but 5 s sounds quite long.

Comment: @Scheff I've been using MFC for 2D text and graphics. Thousands of elements with thousands of API calls have never been a problem - display is instantaneous. I need 100K elements to bog down the system. I will keep using it until I find more performant, high level 3D option.

Comment: So, it sounds like rendering text in 2D could be your rescue option (plan B if nothing else works). Do you have access to projection/view matrices used in 3D rendering?

Comment: @Scheff 2D/3D mix is not an option I want to pursue. I will just stay with 2D. Thank you for you input.

Comment: Sorry, when I read _voxel_ my brain switched to 3D mode (and _vtk_ enforced this). ;-)

Comment: @PaulJurczak Did you try profiling it to see where the bottleneck is? A wild guess based on some cursory investigation of the relevant OpenCV code is that it's the `std::map` that's used to track all the widgets by the string ID... Seems for your use-case there's a lot of extra baggage you don't need. Did you consider implementing it directly with vtk? You could most likely base it on the OpenCV implementation and throwing out anything you don't need.

Comment: @DanMašek My guess is the same: overhead is in mapping the strings, which I don't need. Using VTK directly would solve the problem - I've seen VTK visualisations with thousands of arrows, but I'm not interested in climbing VTK learning curve at the moment. I asked this question to make sure I'm not missing an easy `cv::viz` solution.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Ya, I get ya. Hmm... i haven't really used viz, but just looking at the docs and the code, and thinking about your problem.... could you create some intermediate widget that would combine all the arrows without the overhead, and then add that single widget to the `window`? Maybe [`WWidgetMerge`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d97/classcv_1_1viz_1_1WWidgetMerger.html) can let you do that? Unfortunately I don't have a build that includes the `viz` module on hand to try it.

Comment: @DanMašek I tried `viz::WWidgetMerger` and performance was even worse.

Answer (score 2):

If you have thousands of widgets, creating a single WidgetMerger will be ungodly slow when adding all the widgets together (if you were to visualize the time of each individual addition you will see the exponential slowdown).

However, if you instead have multiple mergers it should be smooth with absolutely no choppiness when displaying, while only being a *little* bit slower on creation.

You can try doing something similar to this:

```
std::vector<viz::WWidgetMerger> mergers(n);
for (double x = 0; x < n; x += 1) {
  viz::WWidgetMerger merger = mergers[x];
  for (double y = 0; y < n; y += 1) {
    merger.addWidget(viz::WArrow({x, y, 0}, {x+1, y+1, 0}, 0.02, viz::Color::bluberry()));
  }
  merger.finalize();
  window.showWidget("merger_" + std::to_string(x), merger);
}
```

**Performance differences:**

Your code as is: `Time: 2522ms` extremely choppy to the point of being almost unusable.

Using multiple mergers: `Time: 6097ms` buttery smooth, no choppiness

Using a single merger: Time > 5 minutes. I didn't even wait for it to finish it was taking so long.

So while using multiple mergers is a slight slowdown initially when creating the widgets, for the display performance, I find it to be worth it.